# Need to check which of my three databases I'm connected to in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database, multiple-databases

My company has three different databases we connect to: Production, Testing, and Development.

Is there a simple way to check which database the site is currently connected to from my C# controller?

Reason: I have my exception handling set up to fire off an email when an error occurs, but sometimes I don't want to receive every Development DB error in my inbox, and would rather only get Production DB or Testing DB emails.

I'd like to do something simple like

```
if(CurrentDatabaseConnection.Name == "Dev")
{
    // don't email me
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that the database that is in use, should not determine behavior.

My suggestion would be to create an appSetting in your web.config that says what "mode" that your application is in.

```
<appSettings>
    <add key = "Mode" value="Dev"/> <!-- Dev, Staging, Prod -->
</appSettings>
```

And then check this value through ConfigurationMananger.AppSettings["Mode"] to see.

Answer (score 0):

You can get to know the database name with below code

dbContextInstance.Database.Connection.Database

Comment: I have answered how you can get the database name in code. This was you were expecting.

Comment: Thank you very very much, @RICKY! It helped me a lot! I am starting my studies in asp.ASP.NET MVC + Entity. I always made my desktop applications all by hand. I was stuck on the need for how to check if the application was connecting to the database. It's so confused if you came from that scenario where you make all by yourself.